# Order of evaluation c#

Tags: c#, linq

I reviewed a colleagues code and told him to reorder the boolean comparisons in the following Linq `Any` predicate for performance reasons. So given

```
public class JobResult
{
    public JobResult();

    public string Id{ get; set; }
    public StatusEnum Status{ get; set; }
    public string JobType{ get; set; }
}
```

and

```
IList<JobResult> jobsList = _jobRepository.FetchJobs()
```

I suggested changing the following:

```
//Exit if there is already a job of type "PurgeData" running
if (jobsList.Any(job => job.Status == JobStatus.Running //1
                     && job.Id != currentJobId          //2
                     && job.JobType == "PurgeData")) //3
    return false;
```

to become

```
//Exit if there is already a job of type "PurgeData" running
if (jobsList.Any(job => job.JobType == "PurgeData"      //3
                     && job.Status == JobStatus.Running  //1
                     && job.Id != currentJobId))             //2
    return false;
```

My reasoning was that most of the jobs in `jobsList` fail the test for `JobType`, only a few will fail the test for `Running` and only one will fail the test for `Id`. If a match fails there is no point evaluating the others and because of sequence points this will not occur.

My three part question is : Is this true, is it provably true and is there a better explanation I can give to my colleague for why reordering is a good idea?

Comment: Keep in mind that an `int` or `enum` comparison involves a single machine instruction, whereas a string comparison is much more complicated.

Comment: You can prove it by moving each clause to a function and inside that function output to a log or `Console.WriteLine` for examlpe.

Comment: I'd put the string comparison last. Thinking any harder about this would be a waste of time. Comparison between 2 ints once or twice is not gonna be your bottleneck.

Comment: I would be more concerned if it is *measurably, or rather, noticeably true*.

Comment: If you were unsure, or only had a hunch, and don't have any real idea whether your suggestion would even work, then you really should not have made this suggestion in a code review, whether you turn out to be correct or not. It's fine to raise the question and discuss whether it *might* be of benefit to change the order, but surely there are more important things to focus on. The point of code reviews is to educate and motivate, and I think that your suggestion probably did neither.

Comment: C# does short-circuit evaluation of the `&&` operator, and if you were using Linq-to-objects then it would be a fair guess that the second and third conditions would not be evaluated if the first condition returned false. However, if you're actually using Linq-to-SQL or Linq-to-Entities your C# expression will be converted into a SQL query to be executed on the server...

Comment: ...That SQL query will then be parsed by the SQL database engine and compiled into an executable query plan, using clues from the optimizer about how best to run the query. While the resulting query will "probably" also follow the same rules, I wouldn't want to bet on it without testing it - and even then, I wouldn't bet my house that the behavior would be consistent over database versions, or even between two different runs (because the query optimizer might change its mind about how best to execute the query).

Comment: If you wanna optimize, don't return a list from db (assuming FetchJobs is returning a list from db) if you just need a boolean value : try to return a boolean from db. Or just return the desired jobs (with a Where instead of Any at IQueryable level) and check if your returned list is empby.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> My reasoning was that most of the jobs in jobsList fail the test for JobType, only a few will fail the test for Running and only one will fail the test for Id. If a match fails there is no point evaluating the others and because of sequence points this will not occur. Is this true?

Is true that the second and third predicates will not be evaluated when the first is false? Yes. Your reasoning is correct there.

Is it true that avoiding evaluation of the second and third predicates when the first is false is a clear performance win?  **Not necessarily**, for two reasons.

First, not all comparisons are equally expensive. Comparing the strings "PurgeData" and "PurgeDatz" requires comparing eight characters before bailing out; comparing the integers is cheaper. It may be in the average case cheaper to avoid the string comparison even though it is more likely to be false.

Second, remember, avoiding running code eliminates the cost of that code, but **you had to write code in order to test whether the other code should be avoided**.  A test is cheap but it is not free! There are situations in which avoiding code is actually more expensive than simply running it.

See my recent article on the subject:

http://ericlippert.com/2015/11/02/when-would-you-use-on-a-bool/

> is there a better explanation I can give to my colleague for why reordering is a good idea?

Yes. You can set a performance metric and a realistic, important customer-focused performance goal, you can demonstrate empirically that the code one way fails to meet your goal when measured according to the metric, and you can show empirically that the code meets your goal when you write it another way.

If you don't do that then what you are describing is a difference you can't measure and no one cares about; your colleague would be quite right to tell you to stop wasting time changing working code in order to make a difference you can't measure that no one cares about.

Comment: I wish more people would understand that trying to optimize code without measuring/profiling/target goal is a fruitless exercise. If I had a penny for every time someone suggested this kind of code change, I can easily retire.

Comment: Salient points @Eric but I didn't write any code to test anything. If I knew an optimisation was provably true in the general case then I could structure my code in that way always. I missed the string comparison expense but then that is why I am here... to be educated on the generally correct way of doing things. I can now apply this reasoning in future and know that I may not be saving any CPU cycles but I'm not wasting any either.

Answer (score 4):

> My reasoning was that most of the jobs in jobsList fail the test for JobType, only a few will fail the test for Running and only one will fail the test for Id. If a match fails there is no point evaluating the others and because of sequence points this will not occur.

Yes, the `||` and `&&` operators [short-circut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) in C#. Meaning, they will not keep evaluating other expressions if the condition has already been met. Given that `JobType` evaluates to `false`, the other predicates will not be calculated. Note that your code may have additional overhead which outweigh the re-ordering of those predicates, such as comparison of an `int` vs a `string` (where the latter will most likely to be more expensive).

This does fall into the category of *micro-optimizations*, and other than explaining what short-circuiting is to your colleague, I suggest you actually test this code to see if it provides any performance benefit at all.

Comment: Short circuiting is the concept I was thinking of. Thanks

Comment: I think you've captured the concept of short-circuiting contrasted with the expense of comparisons reasonably well and drawn attention to the fact that I may have been focussing on the wrong thing.

Answer (score 4):

Personally I wouldn't mind this too much. The overhead of using LINQ is much more than the comparison itself. And if the first predicate evaluates to false, all others are ignored, so testing the least likely first is a good idea.

Going on the expensiveness of evaluation, enums are integers, so comparing an enum is cheaper than evaluating a string as a whole. The second evaluation is an integer too, so the less than comparing a string. I thought `string` compared length first, so that would be an integer comparison too, comparing each character costs more. So if the string is equally long as where it is compared to, the evaluation of string is heavier than integers. Else it doesn't matter too much.

Comment: Some helpful optimisations here. I will suggest changing JobType from a string to an enum. It sounds like this would provide more of a performance boost than reordering.

Comment: Indeed. If possible at all that would be an option.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy to waste hours optimizing things which are not slow.

If you have to ask which method is faster, you cannot tell the difference (ie. both are fast enough).

Linq queries sometimes get converted into SQL, so speed may depend on your database's internal implementation, which is beyond your control.